# HTML in shiny not working locally but works fine on browser

Tags: html, shiny

The below application when launched on browser works fine but when opened locally, the displacements are not working properly. Please refer the below screen shots for reference.
Is there a need to install any libraries for this?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(tags$style(".act_button {
 width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
  border: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  place-content: space-between;
}",".act_button>span {
  padding: 5px;
}",
".act_button>.right {
  justify-self: end;
}",".act_button>.left {
  justify-self: start;
}"),
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Inputs"),
  fluidRow(
    # actionButton("modify","Modify"),
    actionButton("show",class = "act_button", list(span(class="top left", "Top left"), span(class="top right", "Top right"))),
           DTOutput("table2")
  ) # close fluid row
) # close fluid page

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # rv <- reactiveValues(mat = matrix3Input("matrix", default_mat), input = default_mat)
  hide("table2")
  
  # browser()
  observeEvent(input$show,{
    show("table2")
    hide("show")
    hide("hide")
  })
  

  
  output$table2 <- renderDT({
    datatable(head(iris), rownames = TRUE)
  })
  
} # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Locally

[image]

Browser

[image]

Comment: Very strange! I can't say with certainty what's the problem or how to fix it, but I discovered that it only happens in RStudio's browser, even when stripped out to the bare minimum, just the button with the spans. It may be that RStudio's browser does not support `justify-self`. That's my guess.

Comment: I learned that RStudio's browser **does support** `justify-self`, I tested it. But the grid layout may be malformed as you have it.  The `display:grid` rules apply to block elements such as divs, but not to buttons in this browser. That makes sense to me. The difference in browsers may have to do with strict following of CSS rules or something like that. Not sure. But what I found is that if you swap the `button` for a `div` element, the rules apply as expected.